# How to understand JS object structure from Chrome console.log() output?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, mobx

Example:

What does does (...) indicate as a property value?

When a property has dropdown tag vs without a dropdown tag - what does this indicate?

(the following snippet uses mobx action & action.bound - though these do not influence the question at hand)

[image: Implementation of Store class containing different function declarations]

Comment: `...` means it's managed by a getter so you need to click it, which will invoke the getter. The dropdown displayed on objects - functions are objects.

Comment: Why doesn't 'the dropdown is displayed on objects' apply to 'unboundActionBound' in this example? (it has no dropdown)

Comment: Because it's not an object. Devtools will only know what's inside when you click `...` to invoke the getter.

Comment: Have you ever tried toJS function ? for instance console.log(toJS(yourObservableObject));

Comment: So, (...) place-holds for a dynamically computed value like 'get' (or does (...) only *ever* apply to 'get'?)
and:
'dropdown' indicates an identifier who's value is an object reference?

Answer (score 1):

Please use mobx `toJs` function for logging into console:

```
var obj = mobx.observable({
    x: 1
});

var clone = mobx.toJS(obj);
console.log(clone);
```

[further info.](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/tojson.html)

---

- If you are using `mobx-state-tree` instead of `toJS` use `getSnapShot`.